# Chrome: Prevent Inspector from stealing Cmd-1 to Cmd-9 shortcuts

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, google-chrome-devtools

I often switch between Chrome's tabs using Cmd-1 to Cmd-9 when developing websites. Sadly, when the Inspector is open (and has focus), it steals those shortcuts for switching between its own tabs. Is there a way to prevent this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now optional, toggled using a checkbox in the Setting *General* page.